# How does Java GC call finalize() method?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

As far as I understand, GC starts with some set of initial objects (stack, static objects) and recursively traverses it building a graph of reachable objects. Then it marks the memory taken by these objects as occupied and assumes all the rest of the memory free.

But what if this 'free' memory contains an object with `finalize` method? GC has to call it, but I don't see how it can even know about objects that aren't reachable anymore.

I suppose GC can keep track of all 'finalizable' objects while they are alive. If so, does having finalizable objects make garbage collecting more expensive even when they are still alive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - How can Garbage Collector quickly know which objects do not have references to them any more?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587868/java-how-can-garbage-collector-quickly-know-which-objects-do-not-have-referenc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the [Reference API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/package-summary.html).

It offers some references with special semantics to the GC, i.e Weak, Soft, and Phantom references. There’s simply another non-`public` type of special reference, for objects needing finalization.

Now, when the garbage collector traverses the object graph and encounters such a special reference object, it will not mark objects reachable through this reference as strongly reachable, but reachable with the special semantics. So if an object is only finalizer-reachable, the reference will be enqueued, so that one (or one of the) finalizer thread(s) can poll the queue and execute the `finalize()` method (it’s not the garbage collector itself calling this method).

In other words, the garbage collector never processes entirely unreachable objects here. To apply a special semantic to the reachability, the *reference object* must be reachable, so the referent can be reached *through* that reference. In case of finalizer-reachability, [`Finalizer.register`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java#86) is called when an object is created and it creates an instance of `Finalizer` in turn, a subclass of `FinalReference`, and [right in its constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java#80), it calls an `add()` method which will insert the reference into a global linked list. So all these `FinalReference` instances are reachable through that list until an actual finalization happens.

Since this `FinalReference` will be created right on the instantiation of the object, if its class declares a non-trivial `finalize()` method, there is already some overhead due to having a finalization requirement, even if the object has not collected yet.

The other issue is that an object processed by a finalizer thread is reachable by that thread and might even escape, depending on what the `finalize()` method does. But the next time, this object becomes unreachable, the special reference object does not exist anymore, so it can be treated like any other unreachable object.

This would only be a performance issue, if memory is very low and the next garbage collection had to be performed earlier to eventually reclaim that object. But this doesn’t happen in the reference implementation (aka “HotSpot” or “OpenJDK”). In fact, there could be an `OutOfMemoryError` while objects are pending in the finalizer queue, whose processing could make more memory reclaimable. There is no guaranty that finalization runs fast enough for you’re purposes. That’s why you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

> But what if this 'free' memory contains an object with finalize
>   method? GC has to call it, but I don't see how it can even know about
>   objects that aren't reachable anymore.

Let's say we use CMS garbage collector. After it successfully marked all live objects in a first phase, it will then scan memory again and remove all dead objects. GC thread does not call `finalize` method directly for these objects.

During creation, they are wrapped and added to finalizer queue by JVM (see `java.lang.ref.Finalizer.register(Object)`). This queue is processed in another thread (`java.lang.ref.Finalizer.FinalizerThread`), `finalize` method will be called when there are no references to the object. More details are covered in [this blog post](https://plumbr.eu/blog/garbage-collection/debugging-to-understand-finalizer).

> If so, does having finalizable objects make garbage collecting more
>   expensive even when they are still alive?

As you can now see, most of the time it does not.

Comment: But how does GC find unreachable objects? As far as I understand, it only 'sees' reachable objects and all the rest is just 'free' memory. How can GC distinguish a particular unreachable object if it doesn't have a reference to it?

Comment: `Finalizer.register(Object)` is invoked when an object with a non-trivial `finalize()` method is *created*. The existence of the `FinalReference` created that way ensures that it can be enqueued later-on.

Comment: @VladShevchenko GC marks objects that are alive. Each object in java has some reserved space for meta info, e.g. is it reachable, how many collections it survived, etc. Then, GC scans heap and remove objects that are not marked.

Answer (score -1):

The `finalise` method is called when an object is **about** to get garbage collected. That means, when GC determines that the object is no longer being referenced, it can call the `finalise` method on it. It doesn't have to keep track of objects to be finalised.

Answer (score -1):

According to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--), `finalize`

> Called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object.

So the decision is based on reference counter or something like that.

Actually it is possible not to have this method called at all. So it may be not a good idea to use it as destructor.